# Почему не работает order (bootstrapv4)?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Почему не работает order bootstrap и блоки остаются в том же положении в каком были изначально?

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4  order-md-1">
                <div class="media af_spc">
                    <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/customize.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
                        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="media af_spc">
                    <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/time.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
                        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="media af_spc">
                    <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/music.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
                        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 order-md-3">
                <img class="img-fluid img-rounded" src="img/phone.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4  order-md-2">
                <div class="media af_spc">
                    <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/support.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
                        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="media af_spc_a">
                    <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/send.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
                        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="media af_spc">
                    <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/camera.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
                        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для [md](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options) экранов все работает верно. Другое дело, если вы хотите, чтобы этот порядок работал на всех ширинах, уберите префикс:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 order-1">
    Порядок-1 Order-1
    <div class="media af_spc">
      <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/customize.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media af_spc">
      <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/time.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media af_spc">
      <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/music.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 order-3">
    Порядок-2 Order-3
    <img class="img-fluid img-rounded" src="img/phone.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4  order-2">
    Порядок-3 Order-2
    <div class="media af_spc">
      <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/support.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media af_spc_a">
      <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/send.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media af_spc">
      <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/camera.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: так не работает на md

Comment: ваш код в вопросе, при подключении стилей бутстрап 4 работает, как вы проверяете?

Comment: тогда как добавить чтобы на другом размере экрана порядок поменялся? Как будет выглядеть запись?

Comment: Каком другом? читайте  [матчасть](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes), уже просто неприлично, вопросы элементарные, документация есть, ссылки даны

Comment: col-md-4 order-1 col-sm-6 order-2 будет работать?

Comment: да, написала же, что без префиксов будет работать на всех экранах, а с префиксами только на тех, которые вы пишете